# How do I create an IPN which updates my database when the user buys membership, when they cancel a membership etc?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

How do I create an IPN which updates my database when the user buys membership, when they cancel a membership etc.

Also want to ensure that I have the information that I need securely passed to my database and update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To create a recurring payment use this html form:

```
<form method="post" name="formName" id="submitThisForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your@papypamail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your Membership" />
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="0.01">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="SECURITYCODE" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="page going after payment" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="ITEM DESCRIPTION" />
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="your_listener_file.php" />
```

When the user cancel a membership you must use paypal POST variable 'txn_type' = 'subscr_cancel'. There is a several important points:

1. You must validate the ipn transaction:

   ```
       $post           = array( 'cmd' => '_notify-validate' );
   foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
           $post[$key] = $value;
   }
   $c  = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($c, array(
       CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => TRUE,
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
       CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 15,
       CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 15,
       CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 15,
       CURLOPT_URL             => 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
       CURLOPT_POST            => TRUE,
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $post,
   ));
   $res = curl_exec($c);
   curl_close($c);
   $res    = trim($res);

   if( $res != 'VERIFIED' ) {
       exit();
   }
   ```
2. Second - Check is the transaction exist in your database using the unique key. You must use Paypal POST variable 'custom'.
3. If the transaction exist, just make some simple check:

   ```
   if( !empty($_POST['txn_type']) && $_POST['txn_type'] == 'subscr_cancel' )
       $paypalData['approved'] = 0;
   ```

Comment: Why must I use the Paypal POST variable 'custom'? I thought I could check txn_id against my DB to view whether the transaction exists? I thought you'd use the custom variable to assign the transaction to a user or something of the sort

Comment: Usually I use this 'custom' variable. Set some unique code for more security. See the html form above

Comment: <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
     <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $custom; ?>" 
     <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="H4K679J6Y5T7C">
     <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
     <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
     </form>

Comment: The most important is to set your paypal IPN url, for example your_listener_file.php in notify_url form - <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="your_listener_file.php" />